# multiple MySQL SELECTS in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to retrieve elements from multiple SELECTS into PHP?

Take this one for example:

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT ...; SELECT ...;")
```

If it is possible how can we organize the information ?

I don't think it's as simple as:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

Comment: does your `select` have the same columns retrieve? what are you trying to do?

Comment: it's hard to tell what you want to do.  Is it a `Union` of two selects?

Comment: if they relate you can Inner, left, full outer join these data together.  If they don't you can still join them together using a cross join which gives you all records from both joined tables.  Understanding your table structures is imperative to provide a response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT [blank] FROM [blank]
UNION
SELECT [blank] FROM [blank]");
```

(what the previous people suggested, just how it'd look)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Union` as @JLibert suggested.

See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html